# Relation between canonical bundles under étale maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two integral separated Noetherian Gorenstein schemes over a base field $k$ of arbitrary characteristic whose local rings are unique factorization domains and $f: X\to Y$ an étale map between them. Since we assumed these to be Gorenstein, their canonical bundles $\omega_X$, resp. $\omega_Y$ exist and are line bundles / invertible sheaves.

The map $f$ induces via pullback the map $f^*: \text{Pic}(Y) \to \text{Pic}(X)$ between Picard groups and the rather natural question which arrises at this point is how $\omega_X$ and $f^*\omega_Y$ are related to each other?

Since $X$ and $Y$ where moreover assumed to be integral separated and locally factorial and therefore the Cartier divisors coincide with Weil-divisors, this question question can be equivalently stated in terms of Weil divisors and canonical classes: how $K_X$ and $f^*K_Y$ are related to each other? Is there any explicitly formula known?

If we think of étale maps as algebro geometric pendants to topological coverings, then in case $X$ and $Y$ smooth ($\simeq$ manifolds in topological sense) one could expect/hope that it might hold $\omega_X= f^*\omega_Y$, because in topological setting the the canonical bundles are given locally as determinant bundles of holomorphic $n$-forms and coverings are local isomorphisms.

If that's not the case in full generality for the assumptions of $X,Y$ and $f$ as above, is there at least an explicit formula à la Hurwitz for smooth curves/Riemann surfaces known relating $\omega_X$ and $ f^*\omega_Y$ to each other?

If yes, how general this formula is? Does it only hold for smooth $Y,X$? Depend it on characteristic of base field $k$?

I'm pretty sure that if we drop the étaleness assumption and so allow some even rather tame ramifications then it is nearly hopeless to expect the existence of such formula relating $\omega_X$ and $ f^*\omega_Y$ in such generality, so I hoped that maybe the étaleness assumption might provide the right amount of price which we are ready to pay to have such formula.

Comment: I think they are equal. The singular loci are codimension at least two and on these open sets, they agree. Now use the fact that we are dealing with line bundles.

Comment: @Mohan: right, unique factorization domain implies normal, and singular locus of normal schemes has codim at least two. But why should the canonical bundles coincide over the non-singular loci? Again, topologically this is what one would expect, but I missing an algebraic argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual definition of $\omega_X^\bullet$ is $\pi_X^!(k[0])$, where $\pi_X \colon X \to \operatorname{Spec} k$ is the structure morphism. If $f \colon X \to Y$ is a map of $k$-schemes, we therefore get an isomorphism $f^! \omega_Y^\bullet \stackrel\sim\to \omega_X^\bullet$; see for instance [Tag [0ATX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ATX)]. If $f$ is étale, then $f^! \cong f^*$ [Tag [0FWI](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FWI)], so we get
$$f^* \omega_Y^\bullet \stackrel\sim\to \omega_X^\bullet.$$
The next best thing is when $f$ is a perfect morphism (e.g. flat, or l.c.i., or when $Y$ is regular). In this case, we get an isomorphism $Lf^*(-) \otimes^{\mathbf L}_{\mathcal O_X} \omega_{X/Y}^\bullet \stackrel\sim\to f^!(-)$ [Tag [0B6U](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B6U)], giving
$$Lf^*\omega_Y^\bullet \overset{\mathbf L}{\underset{\mathcal O_X}\otimes} \omega_{X/Y}^\bullet \stackrel\sim\to \omega_X^\bullet.$$
If $Y$ is Gorenstein, then $\omega_Y^\bullet$ is invertible (in particular flat), so this simplifies to
$$f^*\omega_Y^\bullet \underset{\mathcal O_X} \otimes \omega_{X/Y}^\bullet \stackrel\sim\to \omega_X^\bullet.$$
So it remains to compute $\omega_{X/Y}^\bullet = f^! \mathcal O_Y$. For a finite morphism, this is characterised by
$$f_*f^! \mathcal O_Y = R\mathscr Hom_{\mathcal O_Y}(f_*\mathcal O_X,\mathcal O_Y),$$
viewed naturally as $f_*\mathcal O_X$-module [Tag [0AX2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AX2)]. I'm not sure if there is a simpler description of this, but the subtleties of the Riemann–Hurwitz formula for wild ramification show that this computation can become a bit involved.

(Also, while quasi-finite maps of smooth curves are always flat, I'm not sure if a quasi-finite map of Gorenstein schemes is always perfect, so it is possible that the second half of this answer doesn't apply in complete generality. Maybe there are better ways to compute $f^!\omega_Y^\bullet$.)

Comment: Thank you a lot, this covers completly the problem I was dealing with.
One sidenote: Do you maybe know an more "elementary" argument 
for the case $f: X \to Y$ is étale between *smooth* $k$-schemes 
$X, Y$ (maybe it can be weakened to regular) that
$\omega_X= f^*\omega_Y$ (or $K_X= f^*K_Y$ in divisor language)
without digressing into the realm of derived categories?

Comment: I hoped (inspired by topology) that it is possible 
to etablish with rather
elementary tools / "canonically" the existence of
a map $\phi: f^*\omega_Y \to \omega_X$ and argue that
the divisor of the section of $\mathcal{O}_X \to 
f^*\omega_Y \otimes \omega_X^*$ is zero. If $X,Y$ are projective
and $f$ can be prolonged to overlying projective spaces 
then the existence of $\phi$ is rather canonical since the 
canonical bundles are in that case pullbacks of determinats of Kähler bundles.
But what if we deal with arbitrary $X,Y$ smooth schemes?

Comment: Is there
an elementary way to establish this $\phi$ rather 
"canonically"? (Motivation: having this for smooth $X,Y$ 
we can show it following Mohan's hint above with elementary 
methods also for normal $X,Y$ since $\text{Pic(X)} \to 
\text{Pic}((X-\text{Sing}(X))$ is injective).

Comment: If $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to Z$ are smooth morphisms of relative dimensions $d$ and $e$ (e.g. $Z=\operatorname{Spec k}$ and $f$ étale), then $\omega_{X/Y}$ and $\omega_{Y/Z}$ are just $\Omega^d_{X/Y}$ and $\Omega^e_{Y/Z}$ respectively, and $\omega_{X/Z}$ is $\Omega^{d+e}_{X/Z}$. There is a canonical isomorphism $\omega_{X/Y}\otimes f^*\omega_{Y/Z}\stackrel\sim\to\omega_{X/Z}$ obtained by computing determinants in the short exact sequence $0\to f^*\Omega_{Y/Z}\to\Omega_{X/Z}\to\Omega_{X/Y}\to 0$. If $f$ is étale, then $\Omega_{X/Y} = 0$ so $f^*\Omega_{Y/Z}\stackrel\sim\to\Omega_{X/Z}$.

Comment: (The final isomorphism $f^*\Omega_{Y/Z} \stackrel\sim\to \Omega_{X/Z}$ holds for any étale morphism, but in general $\omega^\bullet$ is not computed via $\Omega$.)

Comment: If this sequence would split, ie if $f^*\Omega_{Y/Z} \oplus \Omega_{X/Y} \cong \Omega_{X/Z}$ and then we going to calculate determinants, then I agree that we would obtain $\omega_{X/Y}\otimes f^*\omega_{Y/Z} \cong \omega_{X/Z}$. But I not see any reason for the splitting of this sequence. The sheaves in the sequence are for smooth $X/Z,Y/Z, X/Y$ only locally free, not globally

Comment: See Hartshorne, Exercise II.5.16(d).